# I notice below ClassFormatException in tomcat startup

Tags: tomcat8

I notice below ClassFormatException in tomcat startup with this combination jdk_1.8 & tomcat-8.0.3

```
31-Jul-2019 15:37:41.729 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/apps/IP/IPcenterJ/lib/threeten-extra-1.3.2.jar!/] for annotations
 org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:55)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:176)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2042)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1912)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below mentioned solved the issue.

Skip the jar from being scanned while startup by adding the jar name to a property  tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip in catalina.properties.